# How prove each $k$ there exits infinite set of numbers $n$, are divisible by $m$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for each $k$ there exsit infinite set of numbers $n$, such that all  the numbers $$\binom{n}{k},\binom{n+1}{k},\cdots,\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$
are divisible by $m$.

I think we must use Kummer's theorem to prove it.But I can't prove it

let $p^s\|m$, and  and $k$ have $d+1$ digits in base $p$, meaning: $k=n_{d}p^d+n_{d-1}p^{d-1}+\cdots+n_{0}$, and let $n=p^{d+s+1}$,
then we only prove this all binomial coefficients are divisible by $p^s$.

But I can't.

Comment: $m$ is an arbitrary natural number?

Answer (score 2):

For a prime $p\mid m$, pick $s$ with $p^s\nmid m$, $p^s\nmid k!$, $p^s>k$. Then for any $n$ with $p^{2s}\mid n$, all your binomials are divisible by $p^s$ because $n$ occurs in the numerator. Especially, there exists $r$ such that $m^r\mid n$ is sufficient to guarantee $p^s\mid{n+i\choose k}$ for $0\le i<k$. While $r$ depends on $p$, we may simply thake the maximal $r$ over all $p\mid m$ and conclude $m\mid {n+i\choose k}$ for $0\le i<k$ whenever $m^r\mid n$.

Answer (score 1):

(Note to anyone who already read a previous version: I had essentially the following argument as an answer a few days ago, but had seond thoughts about how well it was explained. I believe in its present form the argument is clear, at least clearer than it was originally.)

For $0\le r \le k-1,$ the binomial $\binom{n+r}{k}$ is the quotient $P(n+r,k)/k!,$ where
$$P(n+r,k)=(n+r)(n+r-1) \cdots (n) \cdots (n+r-k+1). \tag{1}$$
[that $n$ is between the first and last factor here is clear at the left end, while on the right end $n \ge n+r-k+1$ is equivalent to the assumed $r \le k-1.$]

So given any $n,k,$ for each $r$ with $0 \le r \le k-1$ there is a positive integer $A(n,r,k)$ such that $P(n+r,k)=n\cdot A(n,r,k).$ This $A$ is just the right side of $(1)$ with the factor $(n)$ omitted, so is an integer.

For the problem we are given an arbitraty positive $m$ and seek infinitely many $n$ for which each $\binom{n+r}{k}$ is divisible by $m.$ Based on the above we can form an explicit list of such $n$ by defining, for each $t=1,2,3,\ldots,$ the integer
$$n_t=m \cdot k! \cdot t.$$ This is because, when $n$ is given this value, we have for $0 \le r \le k-1$ that $$P(n_t+r,k)=A(n_t,r,k) \cdot m \cdot k! \cdot t,$$
giving on dividing each side by $k!$ that

$$\binom{n_t+r}{k}=A(n_t,r,k) \cdot m \cdot t,$$
which is divisible by $m$ for each $r$ for which $0 \le r \le k-1.$